# Should anode rod avoid touching bottom of Water Heater?

Tags: water-heater

I want to get a replacement anode rod for my water heater. I have a 40-gal tank measures 56" top-to-bottom, excluding legs. It seems the anode rods (multi-sections) come usually in 42-44" or 54". If I get the 54" one, it will most likely be touching the bottom of my tank. Would it be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that the anode rod should not contact the inside of the tank. This would surely damage the inside layer of the tank.

Comment: I agree it should not make contact.+

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a heater element that is not straight. If you think it is hitting the bottom of the tank, I bet you have sedimentation that is being misinterpreted as the tank bottom. In that case, you have an explanation as to why your element burned out, and you have a new project in that you need to remove enough sediment to keep the element surrounded by water. If your element is not straight, are you maybe trying to install it upside down?

Comment: The OP is installing an *anode rod* not an *element*